Difference between CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + Job()) and CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO) + Job()
I wonder what the difference is between these 2 ways of creating a scope?
val scope1 = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + Job()) 

vs
val scope2 = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO) + Job()

I noticed that both create a CoroutineScope. Is there any difference between these two approaches?

It is effectively the same.
Coroutine context (so e.g. Dispatchers.IO) and coroutine scope are pretty much the same thing. They have a different meaning in the code: context is a kind of map and scope is a wrapper on top of this map, which provides various kinds of functionality. However, scope always wraps a context and adding new elements to the scope is the same as adding them to the context.
For user convenience, coroutines framework provides functions/extensions that allow to add context elements both to a context and to a scope. It does a similar thing. For example, when we do CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO) + Job(), then we call the operator:
public operator fun CoroutineScope.plus(context: CoroutineContext): CoroutineScope =
    ContextScope(coroutineContext + context)

It unwraps the context associated with the scope (coroutineContext), adds a new context element, then it creates a new scope using the new context. So this is effectively the same as CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + Job()).

for val scope1 = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + Job()) .
when i click on the + operator. I see that this plus operator code is implemented a lot.
it is different from operator + declare equal
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO) + Job()

If you look into the CoroutineScope.plus, internally it does coroutineContext + context, so it calls the same function as in the first example.

In a simple word here is my understanding.
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + Job())
This creates a new scope with both a dispatcher (for background work) and a new job. Everything inside runs independently.
If the job is canceled, all coroutines launched in this scope will be canceled immediately. The job is part of the scope, so canceling the job stops everything inside the scope.
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO) + Job()
This starts a scope with the dispatcher first, and then adds a job separately. The job here is not directly part of the scope creation, but it's combined later.
Canceling the added job only affects that job itself, not the coroutines already running in the scope. The scope was created without directly tying to that job, so the coroutines running in the scope might continue unaffected.
